# JavaScript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this sample code?
(There is also an Uncaught ReferenceError: rainbow is not defined)

```html
<script> 
  function rainbow() { 
        var temp = "";
        var i, j;
        for (i = 0; i <= document.getElementById("dead_unicorn").value; i++) {
            for (j = 0, j <= document.getElementById("unicorn").value; j++) {
                temp += document.getElementById("dead_rainbow").value 
            }
            temp += "<br />"
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temp;
   }
        
</script>

       
<input id="unicorn" type="text" />length<br>
<input id="dead_unicorn" type="text" />Height<br>
<input id="dead_rainbow" type="text" />Character<br>

<button onclick="rainbow()">Run</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: as per the error: `rainbow` is not defined. You can't call it. So start by not wedging JS into HTML, 1998 style, and instead keep your HTML pure HTML, with your JS getting references to HTML nodes (using getElementById, querySelector, etc) and then attaching event listening (using addEventListener) using functions that obviously exist because they're in the same file.

Comment: where is the js loaded? is it in a script tag or another file?

Comment: There is a typo. Instead of `for (j = 0,` it should be `for (j = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Put semicolon after j=0

```
for (j = 0; j <= document.getElementById("unicorn").value; j++)
```